# In Linux, is there a way of seeing which user updated a file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, users

Does Linux record who last changed a file (rather than created it)? If so, how do I find this out? If not, is there some way of monitoring file(s)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[See who made changes to a file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html)

Install the [`audit`](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) package using the package manager for your distribution and start the service.

Set a watch for a file you're interested in, such as `/etc/passwd`

```
# auditctl -w /etc/passwd -p war -k password-file
```

See the `audit` records for that file

```
# ausearch -f /etc/passwd | less
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no. I've never tried it, but if you want to track users accessing particular file, you can take a look at [audit](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/)

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no record keeping of who modified which file.

To give you an idea, you might check the logs to see who was logged in at that time, and under ideal circumstances, history files can examined.